# My flag status is 'none'?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

What's gone wrong here? This is unacceptable!

[image: Narwhals narwhals swimming in the ocean, causing a commotion because they are so awesome!]

Comment: you are unacceptable

Comment: @kalina I only wrote that it was unacceptable because my question was unacceptable without writing that it was unacceptable.

Comment: The Bridge is leaking into meta...

Comment: the bridge frequently leaks into meta, this is not a new phenomenon - not sure what the deal with your flag status is - I've just been through all of my flags and I've never seen 'none' before...

Comment: If I remember correctly, this occurs when you place a "Not an Answer" flag on an answer that is deleted without moderator intervention.

Comment: Basically Rory is right. The flag was nulled because it was raised and resolved by the same person (you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106360/176080) on Meta Stack Exchange suggests that when you vote to close a question, any flags you also raise on it are nulled, to prevent an unnecessary (and exploitable) increase in helpful flags:

I assume that this has been extrapolated out to answers and that you cast a delete vote as well as raising the flag?  This would likely result in the flag being recorded as 'none' to fit the pattern Jeff describes for questions.